# Get Path to Item on a TreeCtrl

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

Lets say I have this treeCtrl:

```
Root

    Dogs
        Pug
        Lab

    Birds
        Parrot
        Eagle
```

How can I get a the path to the pug item?

EX: I should get something like,

```
["root","Dogs","Pug"]
```

(But using TreeCtrlIds)

Is there a function like,

`getTreePath(Item)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use an iterative approach as well, but start with the currently selected item.  It looks something like this:

```
pieces = []
item = self.tree.GetSelection()

while self.tree.GetItemParent(item):
  piece = self.tree.GetItemText(item)
  pieces.insert(0, piece)
  item = self.tree.GetItemParent(item)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can iteratively call `GetItemParent(item)` to get from the item to the root node as follows (Source: [TreeCtrl api](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.TreeCtrl-class.html)):

```
root = myTree.GetRootItem()
pathList = [item]
done = False
while not done:
    path = myTree.GetItemParent(item)
    pathList.append(path)
    if path==root:
        done=True
```

Note this will give you the items in the reverse of the order you require, use `pathList.reverse()` to correct for this.

Edit:

1. As @g.d.d.c points out, instead of `pathList.append(path)`, you can use `pathList.insert(0, path)` to avoid reversing your list.
2. If you're only interested in the path names, append only each item's text using `GetItemText()` instead of the entire object.

Comment: You can avoid needing to reverse the path list if you use `pathList.insert(0, path)`.  Otherwise, this is a reasonable approach.